# multiple definition and first defined here problems with Code::Blocks

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am trying to learn C. I wrote the simplest program ever

```
int main()
{
    return 3;
}
```

and I get these errors in Code::Blocks

```
obj\Release\main.o(.text+0x0):main.c: multiple definition of `main'
obj\Release\DFDled1.o(.text+0x0):DFDled1.c: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Comment: The problem is with codeblicks.

Comment: change code blocks? get another ide?

Comment: You've evidently got another file in your project, `DFDled1.c`, which also defines a `main()` function.

Answer (score 2):

From what you provided it looks like you have two files in your project:

- main.c - your current project that contains main()
- DFDled1.c - some older project that contains main() as well

Now you should check which files are included in your project, and when you find DFDled1.c, remove it from project

Comment: Thanks very much it turned out to be exactly what you said.I removed the main.c and the other file from the project kept only one file, built and ran it . it worked like a charm.

Comment: @AllanMayers You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't code blocks contain more than one C file?